# Why my Python script is not communicating with the PHP(shell_exec)?

Tags: python, php, shell, shell-exec, sys

I'm trying to run `shell_exec` in my `index.php` for executing `hello.py`.

The problem is that the `hello.py` does not seems to receive my variables from the `index.php`. I can't really find out whats the error is. I'm thinking that there's a problem with the `shell_exec`

index.php :

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('python hello.py "Person" 0');

    echo $output;
?>
```

hello.py:

```
import sys

name = sys.argv[1]
age = sys.argv[2]
print("Hello my name is",name,"and I'm",age,"years old")
```

Comment: Try to use the absolute path of `python` interpreter and the python file.

Comment: Does the user running the PHP script (presumably www-data) have permissions to execute the python script as well?